# How can I check in TensorFlow if any of my model variables is NaN?

Tags: python, loops, tensorflow, nan

My model is:

```
weights = {
    'h1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([num_input, num_hidden_1]),name="h1"),
    'h2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([num_hidden_1, num_hidden_2]),name="h2"),
    'h3': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([num_hidden_2, num_hidden_3]),name="h3"),
    'wout': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([num_hidden_3, num_output]),name="wout")
}

biases = {
    'b1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([num_hidden_1]),name="b1"),
    'b2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([num_hidden_2]),name="b2"),
    'b3': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([num_hidden_3]),name="b3"),
    'bout': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([num_output]),name="bout")
}
```

I know how to check whether a single element is NaN using `tf.is_nan`:

```
def save_weights():
    if sess.run(tf.is_nan(sess.run(weights["h1"]).tolist()[0][0])):
        utils.printflush("weights have nan, refused to save")
```

Of course I can loop over all elements in Python, but for a million weights and biases this is time consuming. Is there a TensorFlow operation that can do this ( iterate all my model variables )?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`tf.reduce_any`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/reduce_any) to check if at least one element of a tensor is not zero.

On the other hand, you may want to check out [`tf.verify_tensor_all_finite`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/verify_tensor_all_finite), which will break the execution if NaN or infinite values are found on a tensor (read the documentation of [`tf.Assert`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Assert) to see how to use assertions on your graph).

In any case, remember that all of these functions (including `tf.is_nan`) create new operations in the graph. It is preferable to create all the operations in the first place and then call `run` as needed, to ensure that your graph does not grow unnecessarily on each run.

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot. If was thinking myself using `tf.reduce_sum` which should return NaN if any of the elements is NaN but was not sure if this is legitimate. It is a shame that `tf.verify_tensor_all_finite` is an assertion, because it seems complicated to handle assertions. Nevertheless I will look into assertions, because I want to avoid at any cost saving a corrupted model.